# Error Occured In the other linker flag

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, google-signin

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBatchQuery", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPServiceBase.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPBatchQuery in GooglePlus(GPPBatchQuery.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLCollectionObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusAudiencesFeed in GooglePlus(GTLPlusAudiencesFeed.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusCircle in GooglePlus(GTLPlusCircle.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusCirclePeople in GooglePlus(GTLPlusCircle.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPOzLogger.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusMedia in GooglePlus(GTLPlusMedia.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusMediaAuthor in GooglePlus(GTLPlusMedia.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusMediaExif in GooglePlus(GTLPlusMedia.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusMediaAuthorImage in GooglePlus(GTLPlusMedia.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusAcl", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GTLPlusAcl_$_Internal in GooglePlus(GTLPlusAcl+Internal.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusAclentryResource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivity", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GTLQueryPlus+Internal.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemAction, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemActionDeepLink , _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemDeepLink )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemAction, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemActionDeepLink , _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemDeepLink )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItem_$_Internal in GooglePlus(GTLPlusActivity+Internal.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemAction, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemActionDeepLink , _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemDeepLink )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusActivityObjectAttachmentsItemImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusPeopleFeed", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GTLQueryPlus+Internal.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusPerson", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GTLPlusPerson_$_Internal in GooglePlus(GTLPlusPerson+Internal.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusPersonStatusForViewer, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusPersonStatusForViewerPeopleInCommon )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryPlus", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPOzLogger.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GTLQueryPlus_$_Internal in GooglePlus(GTLQueryPlus+Internal.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServicePlus", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLUploadParameters", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMHTTPFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPBundleCacheManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPMentionCell.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPImageView.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GTMHTTPFetcher_$_GPPAdditions in GooglePlus(GTMHTTPFetcher+GPPAdditions.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(UIImageView+GPPAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMHTTPFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPShareBuilderImpl.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(NSBundle+GPP3PAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Authentication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPOAuth2SignIn in GooglePlus(GPPOAuth2SignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPOAuth2ViewControllerTouch in GooglePlus(GPPOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OpenInChromeController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPShareBuilderImpl.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPNativeShareComposeViewController.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLBatchQuery", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPPBatchQuery in GooglePlus(GPPBatchQuery.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLCollectionObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLPlusAudiencesFeed in GooglePlus(GTLPlusAudiencesFeed.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLPlusCircle in GooglePlus(GTLPlusCircle.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLPlusCirclePeople in GooglePlus(GTLPlusCircle.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLPlusMedia in GooglePlus(GTLPlusMedia.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLPlusMediaAuthor in GooglePlus(GTLPlusMedia.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLPlusMediaExif in GooglePlus(GTLPlusMedia.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLPlusMediaAuthorImage in GooglePlus(GTLPlusMedia.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLPlusPersonStatusForViewer in GooglePlus(GTLPlusPerson+Internal.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPPOAuth2SignIn in GooglePlus(GPPOAuth2SignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPPOAuth2ViewControllerTouch in GooglePlus(GPPOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
  "_kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin", referenced from:
      -[Login_view viewDidLoad] in Login_view.o
      +[GPPScopes plusLoginScope] in GooglePlus(GPPScopes.o)
      _hasPlusLogin in GooglePlus(GPPScopes.o)
  "_kGTLAuthScopePlusMe", referenced from:
      +[GPPScopes scopesWithPlusMe:] in GooglePlus(GPPScopes.o)
      _hasPlusMe in GooglePlus(GPPScopes.o)
  "_kGTLPlusOrderByAlphabetical", referenced from:
      -[GPPService queryForGoogleACLsforActivity:orderBy:limit:handler:chunky:] in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
  "_kGTLPlusOrderByBest", referenced from:
      -[GPPService queryForGoogleACLsforActivity:orderBy:limit:handler:chunky:] in GooglePlus(GPPService.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: there no pods file i m doing without pods

Comment: Try to remove reference of framework or class and then add that again. 
It may be helpful you.

Comment: @Moinshah, Are you sure you [followed](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/) proper steps. I forgot to add configuration file to my project once.

Comment: Have you ever able to fix this issue?